# How to assign batches of various weights to the existing edges (in Networkx)?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm using Networkx to implement a graph and encountered the following problem:
Initially I have a set of edges (not been created yet) without weights and the corresponding weights calculated from other data:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
edges = [(1,3), (1,4), (3,4), (3,2), (2,5)]
weights = [2.5, 3.5, 2, 5, 4.5]
```

I wish to combine **edges** and **weights** into the following style

```
edges_with_weights = [(1,3,2.5), (1,4,3.5), (3,4,2), (3,2,5), (2,5,4.5)]
```

to create weighted edges by using

```
G.add_weighted_edges_from (edges_with_weights)
```

I wrote the following code but it reported: "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple"

```
edges_with_weights = [x + y for x, y in zip (edges,weights)] #TypeError
```

So how should I modify it to get the desired style? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only concatenate two tuples so also the elements of the second list must be tuples too. You can include that in your list comprehension:

```
>> [x + (y,) for x, y in zip (edges,weights)]
[(1, 3, 2.5), (1, 4, 3.5), (3, 4, 2), (3, 2, 5), (2, 5, 4.5)]
```